# Newtonsoft JSON deserializer in WebAPI2 fails silently when trying to parse floating point into int

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Newtonsoft Json.NET library version 9 with ASP.NET WebApi2 and sending the following JSON to my method

```
{
    id:1,
    items:[{
        foo:1.23
    }]
}
```

on the server, items collection has type `Bar[]`, where Bar is

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

unfortunately, instead of throwing an exception when trying to convert 1.23 to `int` as I would expect, my method gets invoked with `Items` collection being an empty array.

Apparently, the problem is similar to this issue, https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/654 , and should not occur in versions higher than 6, but we are, as mentioned, on version 9 (current latest).

Is there any kind of configuration I can make to prevent such silent behavior? I'm in an enterprise environment, and would like to have exceptions thrown instead of data loss.

**Update**

As short term solution, I've configured exception handling, as follows

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
      .JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Error += (o, e) =>
        {
            // this errors bubble through each parent, we only want to log once.
            if (e.CurrentObject == e.ErrorContext.OriginalObject)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.ErrorContext.Error.Message, e.ErrorContext.Error);
            }
            throw  e.ErrorContext.Error;
        };
```

For now, at-least, i'm getting null instead of entire method parameter, which is better. As suggested by Dbc below, it looks like the error did get thrown, but was then simply swallowed during request binding. With the new handler it does not. Continuing research.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using standalone Json.NET, I get the expected exception `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Input string '1.23' is not a valid integer. Path 'items[0].foo', line 4, position 17.`   See https://dotnetfiddle.net/MA0Cdm.  Could your server-side code be swallowing the exception somewhere via [serialization error handling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationerrorhandling.htm)?

Comment: Thanks, I've already added a similar handler, and also took the hint about e.CurrentObject == e.ErrorContext.OriginalObject from your link to only log exception once. Now i'm trying to figure out, why the error was ignored the first time around, I'm guessing this will be connected with WebApi request binders configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with with WebApi / MVC, as they do not consider partially invalid model reason enough to stop execution.

We have now added a special attribute to achieve this to our base API controller, as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```